# Por que no se me actualiza el JList

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, vectores

No se que he cambiado sin querer pero ahora cuando le doy al **`boton buscar`**, ya no me salen únicamente en el JList los valores que quiero.

```
 private Vector vectorVentas = new Vector();
 private Vector vectorBuscar = new Vector();

private void btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //Si el nombre del cliente ingresado existe se abrira una nueva ventana con sus datos

        if (buscarCliente() && !vectorBuscar.isEmpty()) {
            listaClientes.setListData(vectorBuscar);
   
        }

        deshabilitarFuncion();
        restablecerCampos();
        mensajeClientesEncontrados();

    }

 private String nombreCliente() {
        String nombreCliente;
        nombreCliente = tfNombre.getText();
        return nombreCliente;
    }



//Busca a los clientes que se le solicite
    private boolean buscarCliente() {
        String buscarCliente = nombreCliente();
        vectorBuscar.clear();
        if (!vectorVentas.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < vectorVentas.size(); i++) {
                Venta venta = (Venta) vectorVentas.elementAt(i);
                if (buscarCliente.equals(venta.getNombreCliente())) {
                    vectorBuscar.addElement(vectorVentas.elementAt(i));
                }

            }
            return true;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No existen datos registrados");

            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hola Rosa, hablas de unos JList que no aparecen, te refieres a los vectores **vectorVentas y vectorBuscar**?, si es así, y dada la limitada visión que tengo de tu código, diría que nunca le cargas algún valor (salvo que esto ocurra en otro lugar de tu código, en cuyo caso deberías agregarlo) a estos vectores,  dentro del **for** tienes la linea **vectorBuscar.addElement( vectorVentas.elementAt(i) );**, pero si al vector ventas no le has cargado nada...

Comment: Declaras `nombreCliente()` pero usas -sin mostrar su código- `getNombreCliente()`.

Comment: Ya encontré el error, era que había un método que lo estaba sobre escribiendo por eso nunca me permitía ver el cambio. En si así como esta me funciona.